# If f$(x) = x \arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$ how can I divide it into a composition of two function like $h(g(x))?$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, function-and-relation-composition

The full question is: Let $f(x) = x \arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right),$ $x \in\mathbb R.$  Find the derived function $f'(x)$ by considering it as a composition of two functions, and provide the domain of the existence of $f'(x)$.

I tried doing it as $g(x)=\tan x$ and figuring out something for $h(x)$ but the boundary conditions for the conversion of the inverse trigonometric functions keep confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than looks. Firstly, by the product rule, if $f(x)=xg(x)$, then: $$f'(x)=xg'(x)+g(x)$$
Now, we have $g(x)=\arcsin(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})$. We set $\alpha(x)=\arcsin(x), \beta(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$, then $g(x)=\alpha(\beta(x))$, and by the chain rule: $$\frac{d[\alpha(\beta(x))]}{dx}=\frac{d[\beta(x)]}{dx}\cdot\frac{d[\alpha(\beta(x))]}{d[\beta(x)]}\implies(\alpha(\beta))'=\beta'\cdot\alpha'(\beta)$$

We can calculate  $\alpha', \beta'$ and force through the first equation to find $f'$:
$$f'=x\beta'\alpha'(\beta)+\alpha(\beta)$$

Comment: I thought of that too. But if I express f as f(x)=x g(x), and then show g(x) as a composition of 2 functions, then is it still satisfying the requirement of f to be shown as a composition of 2 functions?

Comment: In my opinion yes. I can't see a good way to easily split $f$ into two functions because of the $x$ term at the front (you can't use $\alpha(x)=x\arcsin(x)$ as $\alpha(\beta)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\arcsin(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})\neq f$). It makes more sense to deal with the rest as the composition of two functions, then deal with the $x$

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Thanks for your help.